# node-hid HID.devices() function returning empty array on windows

Tags: node.js, hid, hidapi

I am using [node-hid](https://github.com/node-hid/node-hid) library on Windows 10 64 bit.

Its installed perfectly but when I attached any USB device. HID.devices() returning empty array ( [] ). The same code shows array of objects perfectly for the device on Linux or MAC platform.

What I have already tried is to install pre build binaries and also build node-hid from source in both the cases, Output is same.

There is nothing I found on internet related to this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you testing with a [mouse or a keyboard](https://github.com/node-hid/node-hid#notes-for-specific-devices)?

Comment: no I am using a barcode scanner device.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of barcode scanners present themselves as a keyboard to the OS, which in your case may be causing the problem, because the README for `node-hid` [states](https://github.com/node-hid/node-hid#notes-for-specific-devices):

> Mouse and keyboards on Windows -- does not work, the OS will not allow it

**EDIT**: also mentioned in these issue comments:

- https://github.com/node-hid/node-hid/issues/211#issuecomment-337666323
- https://github.com/node-hid/node-hid/issues/64#issuecomment-147245995
- https://github.com/node-hid/node-hid/issues/64#issuecomment-217501490

Comment: Is there any way to make them present simple HID devices rather than keyboard devices?

Comment: The second comment I linked to suggests that some devices can be changed from "keyboard" to something else. However, the device needs to support that (in hardware), it's not a thing that can be solved in software.